# can any one help me Display design html code in php?

Tags: php

I need help this code below doesn't show design html when we use echo ... any one can help thanks

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="https://innovationtours.net/wp-content/uploads/logo-v.png" alt="Website new Request" width="250px" height="250px"/>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= '<tr style="background: #eee;"><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" ." ". "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Phone Number:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Country:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Tour Name:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Check In:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Check Out:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>Price:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr><td><strong>The Message:</strong> </td><td>" . "mohamed" . "</td></tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
echo $message;
```

Comment: why to use php ? you can use html by closing php tag

Comment: it works ?, what the error ?

Comment: Check quotes are not in pair

Comment: Don't open a string using `'` and close it using `"`. Either or. Displaying errors or even using a decent IDE could've helped you

Comment: thanks to all My friends

Comment: i want show design html not code

Comment: if you want to display design than why you use php

Comment: "_i want show design html_" What is "design html"?

Comment: html  table design

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes

```
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<img src='https://innovationtours.net/wp-content/uploads/logo-v.png' alt='Website new Request' width='250px' height='250px'/>";
$message .= "<table rules='all' style='border-color: #666;' cellpadding='10'>";
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>mohamed mohamed</td></tr>";
.....
.....
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
echo $message;
```

I am getting output as

[image]

Comment: thanks for replaying me  this not showing design table

Comment: where did you check this ?

Comment: Check this in your browser as local server.

Comment: Your civilization came as first program in our life as "make a Pyramid". Thanks to you